# Best way to get EF 6 command interceptor to participate in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, async-await, c#-5.0, entity-framework-6

Does anyone know the best way to get Entity Framework 6 command interceptor and logging to participate in the ASP.NET Web API stack? The problem I'm having is in the IDbCommandInterceptor instance I do not have access to HttpContext.Current; it's always null. I realize that the interceptor is running on a different thread but is there anyway I can pass the context into the interceptor? In our controllers we are using async gets, puts, and patches and we have access to the HttpContext.Current. The framework is handling copying the web context into our async methods automatically.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Ideally, it is not a good practice to access HttpContext.Current inside Database Layer.

Comment: For logging purposes we are using HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name to get our user guid and during a command interceptor call when logging the sql executed I also want to pass the user to our logging framework. I'm fine with not accessing HttpContext but is there a way to pass specific properties to the thread that the interceptor is running on?

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to access the ASP.NET Request in the IDbCommandInterceptor?